# change password functionality in ATG

Tags: passwords, temporary, atg

I am working on ATG11.2 , my requirement is as below:

User will click on forgot password button, a link with encoded user id  and a temporary password will be sent to email. User will click on the link sent in email and will be redirected to ResetPassword.jsp where he will get an option to fill temporary password which is sent in email, new password and confirm password respectively

I am using ForgotPasswordHandler for this implementation. I have read that forgotpasswordhandler method replaces the password property with the new generated password. Therefore m storing the input box value of temporary password in ProfileFormHandler.value.oldpassword

The values are as below:
Temporary Password :

New Password:

ConfirmPassword

But , when I am debugging handleChangePassword method in ProfileForm it is not able to compare the passwords properly. Please suggest if my approach is correct , or what do I need to override in gmethod if any required.

Comment: Try `ProfileFormHandler.value.OLDPASSWORD`, all capitals for the key.

Answer (score 0):

ATG stores passwords in encrypted format.
You need to store your oldPassword in encrypted format too. The passwords will not be equal unless both the passwords are hashed and are same.